# Getting TravelTime from Google Maps API for Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, traffic

I am trying to get travel time with traffic between two locations.
I have followed the documentation guide with all details, but I always get a fixed traveltime between two points regardless to trafficmodel: (best_guess, pessimistic or optimistic).
Also, I tried to change the value of departure time to different dates in future but I always get the same result.

Edit:

---

I am using a standard API key.
Also, I have tried to change date format for [departureTime:] but did not help.

My main goal is to get travel time on links with traffic.

Thanks for helping.

Here is my HTML and Javascriptcode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Displaying text directions with <code>setPanel()</code></title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        left: 25%;
        z-index: 5;
        background-color: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }
      #right-panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding-left: 10px;
      }

      #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #right-panel select {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #right-panel i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      #right-panel {
        height: 100%;
        float: right;
        width: 390px;
        overflow: auto;
      }
      #map {
        margin-right: 400px;
      }
      #floating-panel {
        background: #fff;
        padding: 5px;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: Arial;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
        display: none;
      }
      @media print {
        #map {
          height: 500px;
          margin: 0;
        }
        #right-panel {
          float: none;
          width: auto;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="floating-panel">
      <strong>Get TravelTime in Traffic</strong>
    </div>
    <div id="right-panel"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=[API_KEY]&callback=initMap">
    </script>
    <script>
      function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12, 
          center: {lat: 30.114114, lng: 31.420595}
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

        var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);


       calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);


      }

      function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {

        directionsService.route({
          origin: "11 The Ring Road, Al Khosous, Al Khankah, Al Qalyubia Governorate, Egypt",
          destination: " El-Shams Sporting Club, Al Matar, Qism El-Nozha, Cairo Governorate, Egypt",
          travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
          drivingOptions: {

            departureTime: new Date("June 14, 2016 11:13:00"),
            trafficModel: google.maps.TrafficModel.PESSIMISTIC
          }
        }, function(response, status) {
          if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
          } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
          }
        });
      }
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What kind of API Key are you using? Is it standard or Premium?

Comment: I am using a standard API key.

Comment: docs states you need to be a Premium user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this has nothing to do with your code. Instead, it is a matter of licensing. Your are using [Driving Options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix#DrivingOptions) (BEST_GUESS, OPTIMISTIC,PESSIMISTIC) which is a feature that belongs to [Premium Plan clients](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key#client-id). The way I see it, you need to buy the license first and use the Premium clientID before you can use this.

> "You must supply a Google Maps APIs Premium Plan client ID when
>   loading the API if you want to include a drivingOptions field in the
>   DistanceMatrixRequest."

Your client ID

*Upon purchasing your Google Maps APIs Premium Plan license*, you will receive a welcome email from Google that contains your client ID. *Your client ID is used to access the special features of Google Maps APIs Premium Plan*. All client IDs begin with a gme- prefix.

This client ID is not a key. It will only work from URLs which you authorize, so you don't need to worry about keeping it secret.

Comment: Because you are linking to the wrong documentation? And btw, OP didn't mention whether he is using a standard or premium API key.

Comment: @MrUpsidown I replicated this in my computer. I'm getting the same values also. When I checked the documentation, which I provided in my answer, it states that you need to be a Premium User to be able to use Driving Options(pessimistic, best_guess, optimistic). Premium users have a different kind of ClientID. What OP is asking for is available only if you are a premium user. If I understood it wrong, then please provide your answer.

Comment: What I say is that you are linking to the wrong doc (DistanceMatrix instead of Directions) and that we do not know if OP is using a premium or standard account for the API...

Comment: HI noogui,
Does that mean there is no way to get travel time with traffic using a standard API key?

Comment: Well read the documentation. I think this is stated quite clearly.

Comment: @IslamGaber It seems so. I gave you Google's own statements from the docs :) I even tested it out for you. Don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer helped. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your date format is not correct ? 
Try :

```
departureTime: new Date("2016-06-14T11:13:00");
```

Comment: I have tried to change the date format. Unfortunately, nothing changed.
Thanks anyway.